# Can not pass kata Pokemon Damage Calculator in codewars , but I can not find error?

Tags: javascript

) It seems my function works well , but I can not pass all test , who can help me ?

Link to kata : https://www.codewars.com/kata/536e9a7973130a06eb000e9f/train/javascript

```
function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense) {
  let key = yourType + opponentType;

  let dataObj = {
    "firegrass": 2,
    "grassfire": 0.5,
    "firewater": 0.5,
    "waterfire": 2,
    "watergrass": 0.5,
    "grasswater": 2,
    "waterelectric": 0.5,
    "electricwater": 2,
  }
/* console.log(dataObj[key]) */
if (dataObj[key]) {
 let damage = 50 * (attack / defense) * dataObj[key];
 return damage
} else { 
 let damage = 50 * (attack / defense)*1 ;
 console.log(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense,damage)
 return damage
}}
```

Comment: DRY? (Don't repeat yourself)

Comment: Why minus for question?

Comment: mplungjan , tests are failed  : expected 600 to equal 300  , run  ATTEMPT

Comment: @Quintis I'm guessing people are downvoting because you're asking people to solve the problem for you. Stack overflow is focussed on specific software question more related to errors (and similar) not "can you solve this problem for me" type of questions

Comment: @ mplungjan run ATTEMPT test

Comment: @Quintis A type will resist the same type, your code considers it as neutral damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. I added a test for  yourType === opponentType and moved the dataObj outside for effectiveness

```js
const dataObj = {
  "electricwater": 2,
  "firegrass": 2,
  "waterfire": 2,
  "grasswater": 2,
  "grassfire": .5,
  "firewater": .5,
  "watergrass": .5,
  "waterelectric": .5
};

function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense) {
  let key = yourType + opponentType;
  let eff = yourType === opponentType ? .5 : (dataObj[key] ? dataObj[key] : 1);
  return 50 * (attack / defense) * eff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Read the question carefully before you do it.**

- You set the wrong effectiveness for the same type

> For this kata, any type against itself is not very effective

- You also missed the case for fire vs electric and grass vs electric .

```
function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense){
 let key = yourType + opponentType;
  let nve = 0.5;
  let neu = 1;
  let sup = 2;
  let basedamage = 50 * (attack / defense)
  let dataObj = {
    "firegrass": sup,
    "grassfire": nve,
    "firewater": nve,
    "waterfire": sup,
    "watergrass": nve,
    "grasswater": sup,
    "waterelectric": nve,
    "electricwater": sup,
    "electricfire": neu,
    "fireelectric": neu,
    "electricgrass": neu,
    "grasselectric": neu
  }
  let effectiveness = (dataObj[key])?dataObj[key]:nve;
  return basedamage*effectiveness;
}
```